# Is it possible to have two waves of different frequency on one string?

Tags: waves, frequency, superposition, string, linear-systems

Would this change for different Hz, Wavelengths, Speeds, or amplitudes?

Comment: Why would it not be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to have two different waves of different frequencies on a string (Imagine driving the string with a square wave; it consists of multiple frequencies with multiple amplitudes; See [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform)). However, the velocity of waves on a thin string are constant and depend only on the tension of the string and the density. Thus, you cannot have waves of different speeds.

Thus, you can have waves of different frequencies, amplitudes and wavelengths, but you cannot have waves of different speeds.